# Filter by active/in-active dates in excel - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have Start and End date columns in my database.

I want to filter by active and inactive. Active dates would be true if Start date is less than today's date and if end date is more than today's date, which I was able to easily do with advanced filter and a macro.

For Inactive dates, Start date is more than today's date OR End date is less than today's date. Because of the OR condition, I couldn't achieve this using an advanced filter. Please advise how I should approach this?

Comment: Please provide more detail, including your existing code as well as any visuals you can provide to assist us in understanding your data.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should in fact be able to do this using the Advanced Filter...you just need to use a formula as the criteria. Google Advanced Filter Formula and you'll turn up lots of examples.

Comment: better suited as a comment I think, since its a general answer to a general question (outside the scope of SO, really).

Comment: Honest question: Why does it matter?

Comment: Reading [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) will help you understand.

Comment: Yup, read that. Where do you think my answer is outside that guide? About all I can see of relevance is "Answer well asked questions". This question isn't that well asked, for sure. But does that mean I shouldn't answer it? My answer advises that you can in fact use the Advanced Filter to do this. Someone else coming here with the same question probably needs to know that, as does the OP. The comments pop-up says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments". I'm giving an answer, not suggesting improvements not asking for more info.